# events for Custom Expanded View added to Status Bar Notifications?

Tags: android

from this link i am able to add views to status bar.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html.
but how to define events for it.
suppose i am addind two buttons than how can i set onclick events for buttons.

this is my code for remote view.

```
RemoteViews contentView=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.demo);
        notification.contentView = contentView;

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        notification.contentIntent=contentIntent;
        nm.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
```

here in R.layout.demo buttons are there.how can i define events can u pls elaborate it.
thankx

Answer (score 1):

On your `RemoteViews`, call `setOnClickPendingIntent()`, supplying a `PendingIntent` that will be invoked when that button is clicked.